# Copy all words from widget on a website to a word file with a single operation

Tags: web, text-editing

How could I select all words in a widget on a website simultaneously? For example, I'd like to select all words in the widget called "Skills" on the following website:

https://opportunities.aiesec.org/search?type=1

The goal is copy in a word file the words: 3D MAX, ABAP etcetera that appear in the "Skills" box with a single operation.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Given that the popdown is built on the fly by the website I doubt whether it is easy to do ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Under Firefox, use contextual menu on the widget, choose "inspect element".
- In the console use contextual menu on the code of the div, choose "edit as HTML".
- Select all (ctrl+a) and copy (ctrl+c).
- Open a text editor supporting regular expression (I use [jedit](http://jedit.org/)).
- In a new file, paste (ctrl+v).
- Remove HTML tags (replace "<[^>]+>" by "").
- Remove empty lines (replace "^$\n" by "").

[Here is the result](https://framabin.org/?f289588d5b4badeb#gN25hP4KEnLt+Q/1LUK7KscKHbi9J2jlO09m2iwKgE4=).

Comment: Hi @Setop, I went to console, but I don't see any code of div. Where is it? Could you post an image please?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi see http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/17/1493564823-screenshot-from-2017-04-30-16-51-19.png

Comment: Hi @Setop, the only command which does not work correctly is replace "^$\n" by "". In jedit, the statement delete only some empty lines.

Comment: I solved the problem with ^\s*$\n. Thank you anyway @Setop.

Comment: I missed a step in jedit, after paste : select all and pres shit+tab until all white spaces on the left are removed.

Comment: Hello @Setop, if possible, can you keep an eye on this question please? https://superuser.com/questions/1470125/copying-specific-field-of-a-website-in-a-word-file-with-a-single-operation