# Copying specific field of a website in a word file with a single operation

Tags: web, text-editing

I'd like to copy the field title of each occurences [here](https://www.immobiliare.it/vendita-case/roma/centro-storico/?criterio=rilevanza) in a word file with a single operation. Example of titles:

1. Bilocale piazza del Popolo, Piazza del Popolo, Roma
2. Trilocale via dei Banchi Vecchi, Via Giulia, Roma
3. etc.

I tried to use "inspect element" in Firefox, but I can select only one title at a time (you can use any browser you want).

---

EDIT

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can I use curl and Linux? ( I'm not a Windows person, and am on my cellphone at the moment but it seems to me you want to get the raw HTML and then munge it to produce a simple output either as a CSV you can load or display in a text editor you can copy and paste )

Comment: Hello @davidgo, unfortunately Linux is unknown to me.

Answer (score 0):

- open console with "F12"
- open javascript scratchpad with "Shift+F4"
- type in "allow pasting" to ... allow pasting
- remove or comment "allow pasting" as it is not javascript syntax
- paste the following code :

```
    var sel = document.querySelectorAll("li.listing-item > div > div > p")
    sel.forEach((e) => console.log(e.innerText))
```

- type CTRL+R to execute the code
- get the result in the console.

Comment: Hello @Setop, where is "allow pasting"? I uploaded an image of the javascript scratchpad above.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi You physically type "allow pasting" into the console and press `Enter`. Pasting is then unlocked.

Comment: @Setop `Exception: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '>'` (after `Pretty Print -> Run`).

Comment: Hi @Setop, after running the console gives me the following error (it is due to the command "allow pasting" because it occurs also if I do not enter the code you wrote above): Exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier
@Scratchpad/1:10

Comment: Hi @Anaksunaman, does "allow pasting" work in your javascript scratchpad?

Comment: @GennaroArguzii "Allow pasting" works but unfortunately the listed answer does not.

Comment: I added an instruction to remove "allow pasting" to prevent syntax error